# Get only date from an datetimeoffset property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have using EF to query data from DB , one of my fields is datetimeoffset and i want its value(date only) to be compared with a datetime object. The problem is that when i tried entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime this wont make the offset go away as TruncateTime returns a DateTimeOffset object. I cannot also use .

Date as it will throw an entity to linq exception.

```
entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FromTime) == (assignmentDate)
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried ?

Comment: I cannot paste the entire query but this is the where class `entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FromTime) == (assignmentDate)`
The assignmentDate is the DateTime search field x.FromTime is the DB DateTimeOffset field

Comment: Can you try converting assignmentDate to datetimeoffset range. This may not be right solution. But a way till you get right solution.

Comment: @Vijay am trying the same

Answer (score 1):

DateTimeOffset has a Date property that returns the date only part as a DateTime, so something along the lines of:

```
x.FromTime.Value.Date == (assignmentDate)
```

might work. However, bear in mind that x.FromTime and the value returned by TruncateTime are Nullable so you need to use the value and handle nulls appropriately.

Comment: i can't call the .Date method in Entity - Linq

Comment: This will result in  "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" exception. LINQ converts the assignmentDate to datetime offset for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.FromTime.UtcDateTime == assignmentDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something  like  the folowing

```
entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FromTime).Equals(assignmentDate)
```

beccause `==` is used on  an expression of type object it will be resolved to system.Object.ReferenceEquals

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply truncatetime to both to get the result you are looking for.

```
x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime (x.FromTime) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(assignmentDate)
```

When I tried LINQ was converting the assignmentDate to DateTimeOffset. Even after truncate time it was failing because date had a different offset.

This will generate a SQL something like below

```
((convert (datetimeoffset, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[FromTime], 102) + ' 00:00:00 ' +  Right(convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[FromTime], 121), 6)  ,  102)) =  CAST( convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102) AS datetimeoffset)) 
OR ((convert (datetimeoffset, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[FromTime], 102) + '' 00:00:00 '' +  Right(convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[FromTime], 121), 6)  ,  102) IS NULL) 
 AND (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102) IS NULL))
```